# Excel list - how to select/copy only 5 values of each item?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a list containing 400 items with customer names as follows:

```
ItemName    CustName    MobileNo
```

I need to make a new list that only 5 customers is selected/copied for every item in a single go so that 5 X 400 = 2000 customers should be on list. The output should be like

[image: example table]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? If you haven't tried anything, then you should not expect to get (high quality) answers. Otherwise, please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "ItemName" starts at A2 & "CustNumber" starts at B2. Put :

```
=IF(MOD(B2,5)=1,A1+1,A1)
```

in A2, and

```
=IF(MOD(B2,5)=1,A1+1,A1)
```

in B2

then drag downwards.

pls share if solution works/not/understandable.